# Conservative extension of an empty theory

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Say we have the language $L = \{C, P\}$ where $C$ is a nullary predicate and $P$ a unary one. Then we consider the empty theory $E$ over the language $L$. What does a conservative extension of $E$ look like? My intuition is that it can contain no formulas with the $C, P$ predicates, is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote, and I've upvoted to compensate.

Comment: You are obviously working with the definition of a theory as any set of sentences (a set of axioms) rather than as a deductively closed set of of sentences (the set of all consequences of some set of axioms). I find the notion of conservative extension is simpler to state and understand if you think about deductively closed sets of sentences first and axioimatizations second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially right, with a couple caveats:

- Not every sentence not using $C,P$ is conservative over $E$: for example, "$\forall x,y(x=y)$."
- There are sentences involving $C,P$ in trivial ways which are conservative over $E$: for example, "$\forall x(P(x)\vee \neg P(x))$."

It's also worth pointing out that there's nothing special about the specific language $L$ here. In general, if $T_0$ is a conservative extension of $T_1$ then $T_0$ won't have any axioms using the symbols of the language of $T_1$ in a "nontrivial" way which don't follow from $T_1$ already, but this is not a *sufficient* condition for conservativity.

Comment: And, while not related directly to your question, it's worth mentioning [Craig's interpolation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation), which analyzes the extent to which two disjoint languages can "interact." This isn't directly related to your question, but it falls into the same general topic: how implications between sentences rely on overlapping languages (or not!).

Comment: You say that $\forall x,y(x=y)$ is not conservative. Why not? E doesn't contain the '=' predicate, only those two mentioned.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Equality is built into first-order logic directly - it's in the same category as $\forall, \vee, $ etc.

Comment: Not necessarily: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms. For the sake of the question you can consider it being a "First order logic without equality." But I think I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @SlowerPhoton In every article and textbook I know written post-1960, "first-order logic" is taken to mean "first-order logic *with equality*," wikipedia notwithstanding. But you're right if we work in first-order logic without equality.